# Plane mirror with focusing/accommodation Question

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

For plane mirrors, when considering accommodation (focusing system)-- do we account the distance twice? or just the distance that is reflected back to us

ex. if a person is 10 cm away from a mirror -- does this mean that the focusing from their eyes is 10 cm or 20 cm (doubled the distance)?

Answer (score 0):

20cm. Accommodation will be 20cm. If it would be 10cm, then the focus would be on the surface of the mirror. If you want to see specks of dust on the mirror, then your accommodation will be just the distance to the mirror. If you want to see the image reflected, then you need to account with distance to target as well.